# JSONKit NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, jsonkit

Im having problems in `JSONkit.h` using `NSDictionary`. Whats the properly way to use it?

Json:

```
[{"id":"1100","name":"John Stuart"}]
```

Code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *jsonData = [responseData objectFromJSONData];
    NSString *name = [jsonData objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);
}
```

Error:

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JKArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x84b9b30'
```

Comment: The very first line you copied from an example somewhere is wrong.  The outermost JSON structure is an "array" as indicated by the surrounding `[]` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is an array, but your code assumes it's a dictionary and tries to call `-objectForKey:` on it. You might want to try the following:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSArray *jsonData = [responseData objectFromJSONData];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonData) {
        NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);
    }
}
```